# pixel tracing not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

so i got an image with a curve, and i got a function that looks for 1 pixel and then connect the adjacent pixels (like forming a path), but somehow when it is going south-west or west it does not find any pixels even if there is one.

the function goes like:

```
    pixels=img.getpixels()
    window=((1,0),(0,-1),(-1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,1))
    objs=[]
    obj=[pixels.pop(),]    
    while pixels:
            p=obj[-1]
            neighbours=tuple((x+p[0],y+p[1]) for x,y in window)
            for n in neighbours:
                    if n in pixels:
                        obj.append(n)
                        pixels.remove(n)
                        break
            if p==obj[-1]:
                objs.append(obj)
                obj=[pixels.pop(),]
```

and an example of the failure:

[the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw9dH.png)

[the objects image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvdnk.png)

each different color represents a different "object"
should it not be showing just one object?

i appreciate any thoughts on this, tyvm :D

Comment: None of these pixels require diagonal jumps, though... there is no difference between the jumps where it 'fails' and the jumps inside the dark purple or green parts. (That said, I'm not too well-versed in Py syntax to really see what this code does)

Comment: hey ty for answering, i forgot to put going west too. but like you said there is no difference between thoses jumps, so it should be part of only 1 object(or 1 color), but somehow it is not.

Comment: Does `pixels.pop()` yield a pixel at the end of the line, or is it a random one in the middle? It could be starting in the middle, and track until one end of the line, then start again in the middle of the remaining bit, and track until one end, then start again in the middle of the remaining bit, ... etc. etc.

Comment: That is to say, try to start your algorithm at a pixel that has only one neighbor.

Comment: guess you are right! i tried passing the upper left most pixel and it indeed returned just one object, tyvm.

Comment: thing was i had a more complex algorithm that find a path in a drawing and when a object is completed it looks for any object that starts or ends and joins them, but in the end i always got small lines like these no matter what. so i guess i need to implement some sort of direction as to not create theses 'chunks' objects x'D tyvm